# How can I make a TextView to bypass other TextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to implement next functionality. I have a `ListView` each item of it contains four `TextViews` (contact name,date,message subject,message body):
They are placed in such a way:

```
 ___Name textView___    ___Date textview_____

___Subject textview__   __Message textview___
```

Message body TextView contains large text of the message. So at first I show only part of it but when I click on context menu button Read More i want message body `TextView` to expand in such a way to show all the text:

```
___Name textView___    ___Date textview_____

___Subject textview__  __Message textview___

___Message textview continue________________

___Message textview continue________________
```

So is there some way to implement such a trick? Or at least to simulate such a functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your TextView with SingleLine = true; And when "read more" is clicked , make it false .. Might work..

Answer (score 0):

You can `setMaxLines(`) on the `TextView` and reset it when the user clicks the continue-button. You could also give the `TextView` a fixed height (100dp) and set the height to `wrap-content` on click, but that might not look good as lines could be half-visible.

Answer (score 0):

> So is there some way to implement such a trick? Or at least to
>   simulate such a functionality?

If the stadard useage doesn't satisfy your needs, here is the other solution.

It is, I did a dynamic resize of components at runtime.

In Java code, at runtime( orientation change ans so on) I got reference to my component  (TextView and EditText) with `findViewById`. After this asked for layout params with `getLayoutParams`()  I did a cast and changed position and size.

That I would recommend for you too: on event based change properties of your components, even add more, or delete/hide.